# Getting arguments of heplot function from heplots R package

Tags: r, statistics, multivariate-testing

Getting arguments of an `R` function is quite easy and can be extracted by `args(functionname)`. But I could not figured out how to get the arguments of `heplot` function from `heplots` package.

```
library(heplots)
?heplot
args(heplot)

function (mod, ...) 
NULL
```

I want to get the following part:

```
## S3 method for class 'mlm'
heplot(mod, terms, hypotheses, term.labels = TRUE,
    hyp.labels = TRUE, err.label="Error", label.pos=NULL,
    variables = 1:2, error.ellipse = !add, 
    factor.means = !add, grand.mean = !add, remove.intercept = TRUE,
    type = c("II", "III", "2", "3"), idata=NULL, idesign=NULL,
    icontrasts=c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"),
    imatrix=NULL, iterm=NULL, markH0=!is.null(iterm),
    manova, size = c("evidence", "effect.size"),
    level = 0.68, alpha = 0.05, segments = 40, 
    center.pch = "+", center.cex=2,
    col = getOption("heplot.colors", 
               c("red", "blue", "black", "darkgreen", 
                 "darkcyan","magenta", "brown","darkgray")),
    lty = 2:1, lwd = 1:2, 
    fill=FALSE, fill.alpha=0.3,   
    xlab, ylab, main = "", xlim, ylim, axes=TRUE, offset.axes, 
    add = FALSE, verbose = FALSE, warn.rank = FALSE, ...)
```

Comment: Can you provide some test data?

Comment: @voidHead - this data is complete. The function is all the data that is required for `args` to work.

Comment: Try `args(heplot.mlm)` as the function is calling a method specifically for an object of class `mlm`

Comment: @thelatemail: Error in args(heplot.mlm) : object 'heplot.mlm' not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`heplot` is an S3 generic function. It uses a method, `heplot.mlm`, which is a non-exported function.  You can access that information by first looking at the function body of `heplot`.  If you see `UseMethod` in a function body, the function uses a method.  All the available methods for S3 generic functions can be accessed with `methods`

```
> methods(heplot)
```

To access a non-exported function, you can use `:::`.  Wrap that call with `args` and you have the argument list you're looking for.

```
> args(heplots:::heplot.mlm)
# function (mod, terms, hypotheses, term.labels = TRUE, hyp.labels = TRUE, 
#     err.label = "Error", label.pos = NULL, variables = 1:2, error.ellipse = !add, 
#     factor.means = !add, grand.mean = !add, remove.intercept = TRUE, 
#     type = c("II", "III", "2", "3"), idata = NULL, idesign = NULL, 
#     icontrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"), imatrix = NULL, 
#     iterm = NULL, markH0 = !is.null(iterm), manova, size = c("evidence", 
#         "effect.size"), level = 0.68, alpha = 0.05, segments = 40, 
#     center.pch = "+", center.cex = 2, col = getOption("heplot.colors", 
#         c("red", "blue", "black", "darkgreen", "darkcyan", "magenta", 
#             "brown", "darkgray")), lty = 2:1, lwd = 1:2, fill = FALSE, 
#     fill.alpha = 0.3, xlab, ylab, main = "", xlim, ylim, axes = TRUE, 
#     offset.axes, add = FALSE, verbose = FALSE, warn.rank = FALSE, 
#     ...) 
# NULL
```

Note:  This function obviously has a lot of arguments, so

```
> formals(args(heplots:::heplot.mlm))  ## or as.list()
```

might be a nicer, more readable way to go through the argument list.

Comment: Thanks @Richard for your help and providing nice solution.